# Devops notifications with terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, hashicorp

**EDIT after "Needs details or clarity" remark**

Is it possible to create the Azure Devops Notifications with terraform? To create the team and create the notifications with supported subscriptions and assign that team to receive the emails?

My goal is to create some notifications, such as if pipeline fails dedicated team will receive the email that it has faild, or notifies the team when a run stage approval is pending on them ( see below image for example), using terraform.
[image]

Unfortunelty could not find anything related to that on this [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/resources/agent_pool). Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this resource is currently unsupported by the provider according to https://github.com/microsoft/terraform-provider-azuredevops/issues/907

You could try using the [local-exec](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) provisioner or the [restapi](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Mastercard/restapi/latest) provider in the meantime.